# Elegantly hiding the navbar in a single page MEAN app.

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I have an app that has a navbar on everypage, so I factored it out into index.jade that inherits from my layout.jade file. This is fine for 99% of my app.

The only place it runs into issues is on the login screen as it just feels weird to have a navbar at the login screen, so I used angular to check a boolean against a $rootScope variable and hide the navbar if you are on the homepage.

This is okay but the navbar still loads for a split second, then it disappears. I know I could correct this by not factoring it out into a single file and just cramming it into every single jade file besides the login page, but this would be a maintenance nightmare.

Is there a way that I can keep my navbar factored out, hide it on the login screen using ng-hide, and not load at all until I login.

This is my code to give you an idea of what I did.

The controller that checks to see if you are at the root of the app ('/')

```
angular.module('app').controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $http, mvIdentity, mvNotifier, mvAuth, $location, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.currentPath = $location.path();
 ....
 ....
```

The jade file that shows how this variable is being used to hide the navbar

```
block main-content
  section.content

  nav.navbar.navbar-default(ng-hide='currentPath=="/"', role='navigation')
....
....
....
```

Then upon successful login, the currentPath variable gets set to false to bring the navbar back.

```
$rootScope.currentPath = false;
```

I would like to keep this set up because that means any changes to the navbar can be made in a single file and would be inherited across the app, cutting maintenance down tremendously, but I would like for the navbar to wait to load until login. As opposed to flickering from shown, then to hidden, and then to shown again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this.

The reason you're seeing things flash up is because the page loads before angular has bootstrapped and applied `ng-hide`.

There are two approaches to solve this.

#### 1. Put your script files in the `head` of the page

This is my preferred approach. By putting the script files in the `head` element, the page won't render until the scripts have loaded. This means angular will bootstrap the page first, and when it *does* render, the `ng-hide` will be correctly applied.

Some people prefer the page to start loading first, so won't use this method, but I personally don't think it matters.

#### 2. Use [`ngCloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) on the elements you need to hide

Basically, by applying the `ngCloak` directive to elements, and embedding the style provided in the link, you can hide certain elements until after the page is loaded. Essentially all `ngCloak` does is applies `display:none` to elements and removes it when angular finishes loading.

Comment: Excellent Response! I fixed the error, as you stated, by simply moving the LoginCtrl to the top of the page, leaving the other controllers at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and concise solution!